# recovery push button not working- Amlogic android box

Tags: kernel, android-source, bootloader, u-boot

I am working on a ROM for android 7.1 with uboot bootloader. I have a p212 board (with amlogic s905x chip). The problem is recovery push biutton. (Which you can hold it to enter recovery mode)

Anyone knows what is the cause of problem? I guess maybe uboot but not sure..

Thanks

Comment: When experimenting with U-Boot it is preferable to boot from SD-Card. There seem to be some advices on the net for unbricking the board but I am not sure if that won't ruin the board: https://forum.freaktab.com/forum/tv-player-support/amlogic-based-tv-players/s905x/others-aml-s905x/knowledge-tutorials-au/642382-unbrick-s905x-p212-pin-short-method

Comment: I am not afraid of bricking the device. (After all I can short the MMC pins and burn new image) but I just want to know how can I find out which GPIO is connected to reset push button and how I can fix it in uboot code... Thanks @Xypron